# I have AWS Postgres instance in private subnet and I don't have any VPN, How Can I access it through Local?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, ssh-tunnel

I have a Postgres instance under the private subnet, I don't have VPN configured to connect, even it's not allowed with my Bastion ( jump node ).
Is there any way to connect it through my local machine to testing for development?

The default port is 5432.
and I have ssh access to my application server through Bastion node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have ssh access to your application server through Bastion.
Then you may create two-level ssh tunnel proxy. As Postgres is not allowed even though Bastion node, only allowed through the application server.

1: Create a tunnel from the Application Server to the bastion node.

ssh-add ~/**.ssh/id_rsa** ;ssh -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no -Att -l **USER_NAME BASTION IP** ssh -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no -Att -l **USER_NAME APP_SERVER_IP** -L 5432:**AWS_POSTGRESS_END_POINT**:5432

(keep open this terminal)

2:  Create another tunnel from Bastion to local computer:
(open new terminal )

ssh-add ~/**.ssh/id_rsa** ;ssh -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no -Att -l  **USER_NAME BASTION_IP** -L 5432:localhost:5432
(keep open this terminal)

3: use localhost or 127.0.0.1 with 5432 port in the connection string (to connect from local machine) instead of Postgress endpoint.

Note: replace correct ssh key path and your user name with boldly highlighted text. and keep open both terminal open to maintain the session.

Answer (score 1):

**Port Forwarding** is a process where you can establish a connection from your computer (on the Internet) into the Bastion server, and then *forward* traffic to the database.

```sh
ssh -i key.pem ec2-user@BATION-IP -L 5432:DATABASE-DNS-NAME:5432
```

Then, in your SQL client, connect to the database via:

```
localhost:5432
```

When the SQL client goes to port 5432 on your local computer, the SSH connection will forward that traffic to the bastion server, which will then send it to: `DATABASE-DNS-NAME:5432`

(You can actually use any port number locally. For example, you could create multiple forwarding connections to different databases, each on a different port.)